# VB NET Compare value with values in list

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to compare one value with some values in a list.
I have the object misGallos with value in `"Taquilla"` and I have a method to add values into the list `excluir` in `misGallos`.

So I want to compare the value of `taquilla` if is in the list `excluir`.

misGallos is a list of object with some object of gallos. Some data in the object gallos are taquilla which is an integer like an ID and exluir is a list of integer.

In the code below I start with two for to compare some of the values in gallos accessing by misgallos.

This code doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
    For i = 0 To misGallos.Count - 1
        If misGallos(i) IsNot Nothing Then
            For j = 1 To misGallos.Count - 1
                If misGallos(j) IsNot Nothing And j <> i Then
                    If misGallos(i).galleraP = misGallos(j).galleraP Then
                        Continue For
                    Else

                        For Each m In misGallos
                            For Each e In m.excluir
                                If misGallos(i).taquillaP = misGallos(j).excluir(e) Or misGallos(j).taquillaP = misGallos(i).excluir(e).ToString Then
                                    MsgBox("contiene")
                                Else
                                    MsgBox("no")
                                End If
                            Next e
                        Next
```

Expect results:

```
misgallos(i).taquilla = 1
misgallos(j).exluir(e) {1, 2, 3}
```

`taquilla = 1` and in the list of `misgallos(j).excluir` there is the same value "1" and viceversa if `misgallos(j)` doesn't have any value in exlucir I want to check if in `misgallos(i)` there are values in exluir or is empty

Comment: What types are `taquillaP` and `excluir`? What is `i`, what is `j`? You do not use a `For` loop that would initialize those. I think you got confused. Start again and you should be able to get it right.

Comment: sorry @MichalB. re edited the post adding more info

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following code of a simple Console application written in VB.NET will help you resolve your problem:

```
Module Module1

    Class MyObject
        Public Element As Integer
        Public List As IEnumerable(Of Integer)

        Public Sub New(e As Integer, l As IEnumerable(Of Integer))
            Element = e
            List = l
        End Sub

        Public Sub Check()
            For Each e In List
                If e = Element Then
                    Console.WriteLine($"Found: {Element}!")
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine($"{e} <> {Element}")
                End If
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim element = 1
        Dim list = {1, 2, 3}

        Dim myObject = New MyObject(element, list)
        myObject.Check()
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Also refer to my comment under your question. I think you got confused a little.